# How to change the highlight color of combo edit box in Simple ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm successfully changing the highlight/selected color of the items in my comboBox ListItems, but it appears another event is called after the comboBox_DrawItem() and the edit box is highlighted with the default blue.  How do I get the edit box selection color to match that of the selection color in the drop down items?

[image]

Code I'm currently using.

```
private void comboBoxChoices_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0)
        return;

    ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
    SolidBrush brushForeColor = new SolidBrush(combo.ForeColor);

    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)), e.Bounds);
        brushForeColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(combo.BackColor), e.Bounds);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(((WorkflowDisplay)combo.Items[e.Index]).Display, e.Font,
                          brushForeColor,
                          new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Thanks much...

Comment: If you don't need interactions with the text of the selected item, set `DropDownStyle = DropDownList` -- You need to dispose of the Brushes you create and you should use TextRenderer to draw the text

Comment: @Jimi interestingly, this control has been in place for months and I just asked our product manager... we don't need a comboBox here.  A ListBox does the trick.  That removes the blue highlight problem.  You are referring to disposing the brushForeColor I created?  Where specifically are you saying to use TextRender?  The rest of this works correctly and follows other examples I've seen.

Comment: You have a `brushForeColor` and `new SolidBrush(...)` in other methods. These graphic objects hold unmanaged resources, you need to dispose of them. Better declare graphic objects with `using` statements -- `TextRenderer.DrawText()` should be used in place of `Graphics.DrawString()`, since that's the class used to render text of Controls. The difference may become more visible when DPI scaling is in place